# CDC is enabled on SQL database, capturing file and not capturing data from few days

Tags: sql-server, cdc

I have around 50 databases on our production server and CDC is enabled on all databases. Recently we observed that CDC is not running for few databases and it was running fine when we verified last time. Generally we check whether CDC is running or not is based on "`is_cdc_enabled"` column has to be 1 in `"sys.databases"` table.

The problem is, `is_cdc_enabled` column is 1 and it has `"_Cleanup"` and `"_capture"` jobs are present under Agent jobs. But CDC is not capturing any values. Is there any way to identify on which database CDC is broken. What is the reason why CDC is stopped working suddenly. Please help me..

Comment: Did you check the SQL Server logs?

Comment: What need to verify in SQL server logs? Please suggest..

Comment: I don't know. For starters go and look.

Comment: Please some one help me on this.

Comment: Did you look in the log yet? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/view-the-sql-server-error-log-sql-server-management-studio